# how to get only the 'title' attribute value from following data in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-3.6

This is the views.py I want to get 'title' attribute from the serialize data

views.py

```
class CalculatView(views.APIView):
    query = CartProduct.objects.latest('id')
    serializer = CartProductSerializer(query)
    choose_product = serializer.data.get('product')
    [sell_id] = choose_product
    querye = Product.objects.filter(id = sell_id)
    serializere = ProductSerializers(querye, many=True)
    choosee = serializere.data
   
    print(choosee)
```

output :

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('title', 'Frock'), ('date', '2021-04-22'), ('image', '/media/products/kids2.jpg'), ('marcket_price', 1.2), ('selling_price', 1.2), ('description', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'), ('category', OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('title', 'Fashion'), ('date', '2021-04-22')])), ('seller', OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('seller_name', 'CIB - Piliyandala'), ('lat', 6.8018), ('lng', 79.9227), ('date', '2021-04-22')]))])]
```

Comment: add the 'title' attribute to your `ProductSerializers` class fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
title = choosee[0].get('title')
print (title)
```

Comment: Thank u for the reply..It says AttributeError: 'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Ha. I see. It's list. My bad. I have updated the answer check if that works out for you